# Parentheses and quotation marks in output

Tags: python, printing, output, parentheses, quotation-marks

Sometimes when I use the print function, parentheses and quotation marks appear in the output. I'm using Python 3.4 and writing the code in Sublime Text on a mac.

Here's an example

Input:

```
a=2
print("a",a)
```

Output:

```
('a', 2)
```

I'd like to show only a and 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is Py2 output ... Mac is cheating on you

Comment: After installing python3 using the default installer from python.org, you will have two versions of python on your system: the pre-installed python 2 which is named python in your path and python 3 that have the name python3 in your path. Python 3 can be executed by typing python3 in the terminal and python 2 launches when simply typing python

Answer (score 4):

**You appear to be using Python 2.**

```
a = 2
print("a %i" % a)
```

should give you the results you're looking for. Or, using the newer [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting) method:

```
print("a {}".format(a))
```

In Python 3, your statement `print("a",a)` will work as expected. Check your build system in Sublime to make sure you're calling `python3` instead of `python`. Run this code to see what version is actually being used:

```
import sys

print(sys.version)
```

To create a Python 3 build system, open a new file with JSON syntax and the following contents:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Save the file as `Packages/User/Python3.sublime-build` where `Packages` is the folder opened when you select **`Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**. You can now select **`Tools -> Build System -> Python3`** and, assuming `python3` is in your `PATH`, you should build with the correct version.

If the build fails with an error that it can't find `python3`, open Terminal and type

```
which python3
```

to see where it's installed. Copy the entire path and put it in the build system. For example, if `which python3` returns `/usr/local/bin/python3`, then the `"cmd"` statement in your `.sublime-build` file should be:

```js
"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
```

Comment: Not to contradict your point. The `print("a",a)` statement is correct but in py2 the O/p is a tuple. It has to work in Py3

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are executing it on Python 3 interpreter?
In Python 2 print is an statment so it takes no parentheses

```
print ("a", 2) // parentheses are interpreted as a tuple constructor
>>> ('a', 2)
```

is the same as

```
print tuple(["a",2])
>>> ('a', 2)
```

or in Python 3:

```
print( ("a",2) )
>>> ('a', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using python 2. In python 2 you don't need parentheses and directly write code as below

```
print "a", a
```